# Laravel Eloquent - get count non-repetitive columns according to another column

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table contains appointments, every appointment has `provider_id` and `user_id` foreign keys.

I want to get counts of non-repetitive users for each provider. Here is what I did,

```
return DB::table('appointments')
    ->where('provider_id', 1)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->count();
```

It returns `2` when I have two appointments with the same `provider_id` and `user_id`, but what I want is `1`.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `->distinct()` and `->count('user_id')` after the `where`

**edit:** Try this

```
return DB::table('appointments')
    ->where('provider_id', 1)
    ->distinct()
    ->count('provider_id');
```

Comment: No! Still returns 2

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the table so I can see the data you're working with?

Comment: I've updated my post, I tried it myself and it seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!